# How to check if maintenance mode is enabled in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

I've been searching for a way to check in PHP if the maintenance mode of my Drupal website is enabled, but I only found some solutions for Drupal 7, which doesn't seem to work on D8.

Have got any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maintenance mode of the site is a boolean value stored in a state. You can access it like this:

```
$state = \Drupal::state()->get('system.maintenance_mode');
```